# Material Ui - Automplete seleted value shows as placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am using Autocomplete in my react project. When user submits the form, i want to clear autocomplete value. But from my observation the value is persisting as placeholder after submit. I am providing code snippet for the same

```
                                <Autocomplete
                                  // key={territoryAutoCompletePlaceHolder}
                                  id="grouped-demo"
                                  className="myDealer__categorySelect"
                                  options={
                                    territoryOptions?.length === 0
                                      ? [
                                          {
                                            SH2_Name__c: "Loading...",
                                            SH2_Code__c: "",
                                          },
                                        ]
                                      : getUniqueListBy(
                                          territoryOptions,
                                          "SH2_Code__c"
                                        )
                                  }
                                  getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                                    `${option?.SH2_Name__c}${
                                      option?.SH2_Code__c
                                        ? `:${option?.SH2_Code__c}`
                                        : ""
                                    }`
                                  }
                                  onChange={(e, newValue) => {
                                    // setTerritoryAutoCompletePlaceHolder(
                                    //   `${newValue.SH2_Name__c}:${newValue.SH2_Code__c}`
                                    // );
                                    onChange(e, newValue, "territory");
                                  }}
                                  renderInput={(params) => (
                                    <TextField
                                      {...params}
                                      placeholder={"Select Territory"}
                                    />
                                  )}
                                />
```

I tried to make place holder dynamic and it solved the issue but now i can not see the clear button as it is always showing place holder. The commented code was done for dynamic placeholder